# бинарное сравнение файлов C++

Tags: c++, файловая-система, ifstream

Пытаюсь написать консольную программу, которая позволяет выбрать две директории с файлами внутри, анализирует их(директории), находит там идентичные(бинарно) файлы и выводит список дубликатов.
Проблема состоит в том, что при реализации сравнения, представленного в коде ниже, если один файл будет равен 1,2,3(в столбик, в одной папке) а другой 1,2,3,4,5(также в столбик,в другой папке)
то программа выдает что они идентичны. То есть как я понимаю, каким то образом считает что одно является подмножеством другого и дает true.
Буду очень благодарен если кто предложит решение и помощь^^
Код реализации метода сравнения файлов из двух разных каталогов:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

void Directory_iterator(){

fs::path dir1, dir2;
bool result = true;

cout << "Введите каталог 1:";
cin >> dir1;
cout << "Введите каталог 2:";
cin >> dir2;
if (!(fs::exists(dir1) && fs::exists(dir2)))
    cout << "Неверно указаны директории, проверьте еще раз";
else {
    for (const auto& p1 : fs::directory_iterator(dir1)) {
        for (const auto& p2 : fs::directory_iterator(dir2))
        {
            ifstream fin1(p1, ios::binary);
            ifstream fin2(p2, ios::binary);
            if (fin1 && fin2) {
                
                char ch1, ch2;
                //bool result = true;
                while (fin2.get(ch1) && fin1.get(ch2)) {
                    if (ch1 != ch2) {
                        result = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (result) {
                    cout << p1.path().u8string() << " , " << p2.path().u8string() << " Равны " << endl;
                    
                }
                else
                    continue;               
            }
                
        }

    }
    
    if (!result) { cout << "Совпадений не найдено"; }

}
```

}

Comment: а если просто использовать генерацию crc и сравнивать результаты?

Comment: @xmikex сделал правильный намек. Вложенный цикл по всем файлам это очень затратное решение. Вероятно, правильней всего было бы прочесть каждый файл, вычислить его хэш (например, тот же CRC32) и запомнить в массиве эти числа вместе с именами файлов. Затем отсортировать массив (одинаковые коды окажутся рядом) и проводить побайтное сравнение лишь для тех файлов, у которых оказались одинаковые хэши.

Comment: @avp не сталкивался с этим ранее, погуглил- действительно хороший вариант относительно вложенных циклов. Только насколько сложна эта реализация вычисления хэш суммы файла? имеется ввиду где мб код подглядеть, гугл мне в помощь?))

Comment: @OBEMA333, в общем, да. Реализаций куча, [например](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2/%D0%A6%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%B0_C). / Если не заморачиваться, можно (в линуксе) просто вызвать через `popen()` команду crc32 с именем файла

Comment: В основном встречаются реализации, которым для вычисления CRC надо передать весь файл. Но можно и по одному символу. `uint32_t crc = -1, c; while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) { crc = (crc >> 8) ^ CRCTable[(crc ^ c) & 0xff]; } crc ^= -1;` Все.

Comment: @avp благодарю за ответ! Постараюсь реализовать и применить идею с crc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша проблема в цикле while, он выполняется до тех пор, пока в обоих файлах есть продолжение.
Как в приведенном примере: 1 2 3 и 1 2 3 4 5, он дошел до 3, видит, что дальше элементов в первом файле нет и цикл заканчивается.

Наиболее простой способ решения: проверить после выхода из цикла, закончились ли оба файла и если нет сделать result = false

Comment: `while (fin2.get(ch1) || fin1.get(ch2))` точно не сработает (будет читать только первый). Остается только проверять, что оба файла закончились. Впрочем, при обработке именно файлов, а не произвольных потоков, лучше всего еще до чтения содержимого файлов проверить, что их размер равен.

Comment: Да, вы правы, убрал вариант с while (fin2.get(ch1) || fin1.get(ch2))

Comment: благодарю за ответ, попытался добавить после цикла while проверку закончились ли оба файла:
if (!fin1.eof() && !fin1.eof()) {
 result = false;
}
но в итоге теперь вообще не находит совпадений, даже если они есть)))

Comment: Вы написали if (!fin1.eof() && !fin1.eof())
т.е. проверяете для одинакового файла, закончился ли он.
eof возвращает true, когда файл кончился, нам нужно проверить, что оба файла кончились, иначе result = false, тогда условие выглядит примерно так:
if(!(fin1.eof()&&fin2.eof())) result = false;

Comment: да, опечатался)благодарю, всё работает)